# Spring Boot. How to disable Initialization of JPA Conditionaliy

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I'm woundering if it's possible to disable the intialization of JPA Stack competelly.

I some situation my application is executed in enviroment where database is not accessible. Application can survive this on application level. 
But technically i get some exception on intialization of Data Source.

1. there musst be some way to disable JPA intialization at all (not needed withoud db. By profile or someting like that.
2. Or maby at least i can say Connection pool to not connect or somethinglike this.
3. Other ideas?

Answer (score 9):

Yes, you could use profiles for that: one with JPA and another without it. To turn off DataSource/JPA autoconfiguration you need to add `spring.autoconfigure.excludes` property (with fully-qualified class names) to profile-specific `application.properties`.

What classes to exclude? I suggest to start from `DataSourceAutoConfiguration` and if it's not enough try to disable [other database-related autoconfiguration classes](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/auto-configuration-classes.html).

Note that `spring.autoconfigure.excludes` is a new feature that is [avaiable since Spring Boot 1.3.0.M3](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Spring-Boot-1.3.0-M3-Release-Notes#auto-configuration)

Comment: Yes, but how to make that "eclusion" **conditionaly** to Profile.
And Secondly: How then to deal with _Autowired_. Would mean in need custom  factories? Maybe some exmaple helps me

Comment: Ok Autowirede can have Required=false... Now i hvae to figure out how to 
make
EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude = DataSourceAutoConfiguration .class) conditional, depending on Profile

Comment: `spring.autoconfigure.excludes` is analogue of `EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude = )` that may be used in `application.properties`. Just put it in `application-nodb.properties` file where `nodb` is a name of profile.

Comment: Here i try to exclude DataSourceAutoconfig, (So it not tries to establish connection) 
spring.autoconfigure.excludes=org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceAutoConfiguration.

But it's not working, no chnage to behavior. Tried with DataSourceAutoConfiguration too... 
Spring boot 1.3.0.M5

Comment: Run application with `--debug`: has it shown as enabled?

Comment: It's not shown as disabled.
Exclusions:
-----------
   org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.WebMvcAutoConfiguration

and this is excluded non conditionally

Comment: I've solved a litte bitt differentlyy so far. WIt expilicite configuration class
@Profile(value = {"dev"})
@Configuration
@ImportAutoConfiguration({DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class, HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration.class})
public class JPAConfig {

    private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(AppCommandLinstener.class);

    _PostConstruct
    public void logStatus() {
        LOG.info("======== DB Configuration initialized =========");
    }

}
and explicitely disabling it in Application.java

Comment: But the problem is it depends on environment not on the property within environment. but it's fine..

Comment: I came across this post after looking for a spring boot data source initialization problem and had somewhat the same issue (in my case we have multiple datasources, which caused a failure). In the end I had to add a property to my spring properties: `spring.datasource.initialize=false`. This besides disabling the auto configuration.