# How to disable spring-data-mongodb in spring-boot

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-boot, spring-boot-starter

I am new to SpringBoot. I have built a simple application which should use fake data in the development environment, and connect to MongoDb in the test environment. Dev environment does not have mongodb setup.

I have tried using Spring Boot qualifiers/profiles to achieve it.

I have a main class which looks like the following:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class Main {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
       SpringApplication.run(Main.class, args);
   }
}
```

I have a DAO interface StudentDao.java

```
public interface StudentDao {
    Student getStudentById(String id);
}
```

I then created a couple of implementations for the DAO, one for fake data, and one for data from Mongo

**FakeStudentDaoImpl.java**

```
@Repository
@Qualifier("fakeData")
public class FakeStudentDaoImpl implements StudentDao {

    private static Map<String, Student> students;

    static {

        students = new HashMap<String, Student>(){
            {
                put("1", new Student("Ram", "Computer Science"));
            }
        };
    }

    @Override
    public Student getStudentById(String id){
        return this.students.get(id);
    }
}
```

**MongoStudentDaoImpl.java**

```
@Repository
@Qualifier("mongoData")
public class MongoStudentDaoImpl implements StudentDao {

    @Autowired
    private MongoStudentRepo repo;

    @Override
    public Student getStudentById(String id) {
        return  repo.findById(id).get();
    }
}
```

The MongoStudentRepo is a simple interface extending MongoRepository:

```
public interface MongoStudentRepo extends MongoRepository<Student, String> {
}
```

And my POM file has the following dependencies called out:

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.3.RELEASE</version>
</parent>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

Of course, I have other controller classes. 
This works fine in the Test environment, where there is a MongoDb, and it is able to connect to it. However, when I am trying to start it in my local environment, it fails to start because it is not finding MongoDb on startup.

How do I disable the MongoDb part in my local environment (and just use fake data)? I want to make the same code work in both environments.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: for `local` and `dev` environment just use in memory `H2` database, you don't need to change anything other than configs

Comment: Did you try an embedded mongodb database?

Comment: Alternatively you might consider using embedded mongodb for dev, or run a mongodb instance using docker (which is what I do).  See: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-embedded-mongodb . This will save you creating and maintaining fake repositories, etc.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem, and found the solution you ask for in this other question:

[Spring Boot. How to disable Initialization of JPA Conditionaliy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32590304/spring-boot-how-to-disable-initialization-of-jpa-conditionaliy)

For example, if you want to disable spring-data-mongodb in the development environment, then, assuming that you run under a "dev" profile:

`application-dev.yml`:

```yaml
spring:
  autoconfigure:
    exclude: org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.mongo.MongoAutoConfiguration
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use an embedded MongoDB database. [Here](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-embedded-mongodb) an example.

Answer (score 1):

Several possible options:

1) You can use spring [profiles](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-profiles.html). Map one bean with `@Profile("test)` and second one with `@Profile("prod")`. To specify which profile to use `--spring.profiles.active=test`

2) You can have different [configurations](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html).

```
application-prod.yml
--------------
mongo-url:produrl

application-test.yml
--------------
mongo-url:localhost
```

Use spring active profiles to select config. To use local profile you need to setup local mongo instance. And you can have several options again: [just download instance](https://www.mongodb.com/download-center/community), [docker image](https://hub.docker.com/_/mongo), [embeded mongo](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-embedded-mongodb).